# iOS geolocation, Code works differently when initialization and declaration happen together

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation

In iOS geolocation, the code works if the locationManager is declared and initialized separately, however it does not work if it is declared and initialized at the same time. Why is it so? The following is the working code sample:-

```
 var locationManager : CLLocationManager!

func initLocManager() {
    locationManager=CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.activityType = .automotiveNavigation
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0  
   }

func retrieveLocation(){
    initLocManager()
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    for location in locations {
        print("Long \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
        print("Lati \(location.coordinate.latitude)")
    }
}
```

whereas the following code does not work:-

```
 var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func initLocManager() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.activityType = .automotiveNavigation
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0  
}

func retrieveLocation(){

    initLocManager()
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    for location in locations {
        print("Long \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
        print("Lati \(location.coordinate.latitude)")           

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `retrieveLocation`?  Both of your code blocks work for me.

Comment: Also both working bro

Comment: I am calling them from an objective c file. Only one of the two work for me and that's really strange

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Create new file with this code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


class LocationManager: CLLocationManager, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let shared = LocationManager()

    public var currentLocation = CLLocation() {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: LocationManager.LocationUpdatedNotification), object: self, userInfo: nil)
        }
    }

    static let LocationUpdatedNotification: String = "LocationUpdate"

    private override init() {
        super.init()

        self.delegate = self
        self.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        self.activityType = .automotiveNavigation
        self.distanceFilter = 10.0
        self.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        if let lastLocation = locations.last {
            currentLocation = lastLocation
        }
    }

}
```

In AppDelegate.swift

```
_ = LocationManager.shared // Add this line to func didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

Now you can get current user location using this code:

```
LocationManager.shared.currentLocation
```

Also you can subscribe for LocationUpdate notification anywhere in your project.